# Socket.io Server emit not executing as expected

Tags: node.js, sockets

I've recently downloaded some demo code, and until a couple of weeks ago it worked fine using socket.io version 0.9, but since I've update socket.io to version 1.0 some functions seem to fail. And I can't figure out why. I hope somebody had the same problem and could explain to me what is going wrong.

Below is part of the code, where the problem seems to start/occur.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var http = require('http');
var socketio = require('socket.io');
var url = require("url");
var stats = require("./statistics");

var socketServer;

// handle contains locations to browse to (vote and poll); pathnames.
function startServer(route,handle)
{
    // on request event
    function onRequest(request, response) {
      // parse the requested url into pathname. pathname will be compared
      // in route.js to handle (var content), if it matches the a page will 
      // come up. Otherwise a 404 will be given. 
      var pathname = url.parse(request.url).pathname; 
      console.log("Request for " + pathname + " received");
      var content = route(handle,pathname,response,request);
    }

    var httpServer = http.createServer(onRequest).listen(1337, function(){
        console.log("Listening at: http://localhost:1337");
        console.log("Server is up");
        stats.initNumbers(); // load previous votes from JSON file
    }); 
    initSocketIO(httpServer);
}

function initSocketIO(httpServer)
{
    //console.log(httpServer);
    socketServer = socketio.listen(httpServer);

    socketServer.on('connection', function (socket) {
        console.log("initSocketIO:connection -> user connected");
        socket.emit('onconnection', {pollOneValue:stats.pollOne(),pollTwoValue:stats.pollTwo()}); // on connection send poll one and two values

        // when message from a client is recieved, send it to all clients
        socketServer.on('pollUpdate', function(data) {
            console.log('onUpdate');
            socket.emit('updateData',data);         
        });

  });

    //console.log(socketServer.sockets._events.connection);

}

function updatePollData()
{
    console.log('updatePollData()');

    socketServer.emit('pollUpdate',{pollOneValue:stats.pollOne(),pollTwoValue:stats.pollTwo()});
}

exports.start = startServer;
exports.updatePollData = updatePollData;
```

From another function it is possible to update the data, by executing the updatePollData function. This function should emit the new data. Expected is that when connected, the following listener would be executed:

```
// when message from a client is recieved, send it to all clients
socketServer.on('pollUpdate', function(data) {
  console.log('onUpdate');
  socket.emit('updateData',data);           
});
```

In version 0.9 this worked fine, but in function 1.0 it fails. It does however execute

```
socketServer.on('connection', function (socket) {..} );
```

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Without more information about the exact error, I'ld say try replacing `socketServer` with `socket`.

```
socketServer.on('pollUpdate', function(data) {
    ...
});
```

should be

```
socket.on('pollUpdate', function(data) {
    ...
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Tried replacing socketServer with socket. Unfortunately it still didn't solve the problem. The client data still isn't updated.

Comment: Console shows the following: `updatePollData()` followed by `initSocketIO:connection -> user connected` in stead of the expected `onUpdate`.

Comment: Well, that looks like it's working. Except the 'pollUpdate' event doesn't fire. I never had a construct like that, but my guess is that any socket (including the server) ignores its own emits.

Comment: The weirdest part of it, is that it does work in 0.9, and doesn't work in 1.0.